# VB.NET System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException Assembly Load

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, .net-assembly, invoke

I'm getting the error "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" or "System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException" when I try to invoke an assembly(vb.net windows forms application). "confusethis.exe" source:

```
Public Class mainform
Private Sub mainform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
MsgBox("test")
End Sub
End Class
```

Thats my source for invoking:

```
    Dim instance As FileStream = File.Open("confusethis.exe", FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(instance)
    Dim bin As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(instance.Length))
    instance.Close()
    br.Close()
    Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.Load(bin)
    Dim method As MethodInfo = a.EntryPoint
    If (IsDBNull(method) = False) Then
        Dim o As Object = a.CreateInstance(method.Name)
        method.Invoke(o, New Object() {New String() {"param1"}})
    Else
        MsgBox("error!")
    End If
```

I tried changing
`method.Invoke(o, New Object() {New String() {"param1"}})`
to 
`method.Invoke(o, Nothing)`
and 
`method.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)`
and 
`method.Invoke(o, New Object() {})`

nothing helped yet, still getting errors.

Comment: Whats the signature of a.EntryPoint?